# How to implement paired connection between server client using RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq

Well i am intending to implement a paired connection between server and client , as of now i have sent chunk of data and code to the slave system using rabbitMq and the slave system executes it . But i am unable to again send back the code to server , since rabbitMq has the classic implementation of Publisher / subscriber model . Is there any way to go around this and ensure that the server also fetches result from the slave systems ? i am using python bindings for rabbitMQ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily simulate RPC semantics with RabbitMQ (or indeed, any messaging system). All you need is a form of correlation identifier so that the response message can be tracked and interpreted as the "answer" for the original request.

Luckily, the RabbitMQ online documentation has an [entire page with examples](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html) on how to do this using Python.

Comment: i did read that , but one vital point i forgot to mention was , the code to be implemented in the slave system will be given at run time . as far as i nknow in RPC ,the function must be defined in the slave systems , before it can be called .

Comment: Forget the term "RPC" and instead think "Request followed by a Response". In other words, your slave doesn't necessarily need a "procedure" which can be called remotely. It simply needs to read a message from the incoming queue, do something with it and then publish a reply message back to the broker so that the master can receive it (along with the correlation ID which I mentioned earlier) and your problem is solved. In a sense, the "procedure" is the fact that you're going to process those messages on the slave and reply accordingly.